# Download files in pdf format no matter in what format they are uploaded

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to download files in pdf format by popping up a dialog box but right now the file opens directly on the browser. Can somebody suggest what should I edit in my code to achieve this.

```
protected void gridContributions_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "Download")
        {
            Response.Clear();
            Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
            Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "Filename=" + e.CommandArgument);
            Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath("~/Match/Reciepts/") + e.CommandArgument);
            Response.End();
        }
    }
```

Comment: The files themselves will have to be PDF files, otherwise, you will have to convert them and then send them back to the browser.

Comment: Your title and your question don't seem to be the same thing...

Comment: Agreed with @David.  Does you only want to know how to enable the user to download a file (as opposed to opening in a browser), or do you also want to know how to produce a .PDF file from an uploaded file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify the file as an "attachment" in the content disposition header:

```
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + e.CommandArgument);
```

Ultimately it's up to the browser what to do with the response.  This header is how the server *suggests* to the client that the response be treated as a file, but it can't *force* that behavior.